# Voltage drop when driving voice coil OpAmp gain stage

Tags: operational-amplifier, driver, coil, pid-controller

I'm driving a voice coil with a PID controller. So far, I've set the gain (P) stage, which is composed of LM358 opamps and a dual +-4.22 rail with 1.5V AAA batteries. This is the schematic, where you can see the difference between Vref and Vi is 1V, so Vout should go to -1V (3.2 from ground). It works like that until I attach the voice coil to Vload. Then, Voad drops to -0.25V.

[image]

Vload won't go further than +-0.25V no matter the the difference (Verr) between signals.

It seems like it's a current issue but, isn't the last buffer supposed to be able to source enough current to drive the voice coil which I can drive if I just plug it to the rail?

Thanks!

Comment: The LT1013 can only source 20 mA of current, you're lucky you're getting 25mA without burning it up completely. Add some sort of totem pole stage with feedback if you want more output drive current.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the data sheet, on pages 4 and 5 you'll see VOUT. Notice that, with a 5 volt supply and 600 ohm load, you cannot be certain of getting more than 3.1 volts.

I am astonished that you are getting .25 volts with a 10 ohm load. This is far beyond what the data sheet suggests. Your op amp is putting out 25 mA, when its rated max is about 5 mA (10 volts into 2k, or 3 volts into 600). I'll bet it's also getting hot.

You need a buffer amp which will provide something in excess of 100 mA, and that's for a 1 volt output. You don't say what your maximum output voltage is expected to be, but if it's 3 volts, you need a 300 mA buffer which is rated to produce that current with about 4 volt supplies.

Answer (score 0):

Check your battery voltages once you connect that 1_ohm load. Still +-4.22 volts?
And does the chosen opamp promise, in the datasheet, to provide 2 or 3 amps drive from only +-4.22 volts?

The datasheet shows +-3.3 volt output, at Iout of 10mA, for VDD = +-5v.